# | "Unable to instantiate activity" |

Tags: android

The main purpose of my project is to create a database automatically when starting up the application for the first time.
I am trying to create a simple database through a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.  The following is the code of this class:

```
public class DatabaseImplementation extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestDatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String createDep = "CREATE TABLE tbl_Department("+ 
                                                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                                    "department_name TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static final String createEmp = "CREATE TABLE tbl_Employee(" +
                                                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                                    "name TEXT NOT NULL," +
                                                    "age INTEGER," +
                                                    "department_id INTEGER, "+
                                                    "FOREIGN KEY(department_id)"+
                                                    "REFERENCES tbl_Department(_id));";




    public DatabaseImplementation(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(createDep);
        db.execSQL(createEmp);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        //--
    }



}
```

Please not that I do not have any layout declared in my layout/main.xml file as I believe there is no need to for the purpose of this project.

The following is my main activity code:

```
public class TestingDatabaseMain extends Activity {

DatabaseImplementation db = new DatabaseImplementation(this);

SQLiteDatabase dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    insertRecords();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testing_database_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void insertRecords(){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("_id", 1);
    values.put("department_name", "HR");

    long newrowID = dbWrite.insert("tbl_Department",  null, values);

}
```

}

When I run the application on my Nexus 7, the following error is displayed:

"Unfortunately, Testing Database has Stopped."

and the error in the LogCat is :

```
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.testingdatabase/com.example.testingdatabase.TestingDatabaseMain}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.example.testingdatabase.TestingDatabaseMain.<init>(TestingDatabaseMain.java:13)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-16 14:14:14.240: E/AndroidRuntime(9979):     ... 11 more
07-16 14:16:47.030: W/ActivityThread(10487): Application com.example.testingdatabase is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
```

I would really appreciate help on this matter, even if someone could link me to other posts having the same problem.  Tried looking for a couple of other posts and tried following the answers that were provided to no avail.

Thanks a bunch.

Edited: I am new to android development so do not scold me for any silly errors :)

Comment: you can perform long operations during the app instantiation. So kindly avoid database operations in the main thread. That will fix the problem.

Comment: This was a null pointer exception error, you didn't initialize the SQLiteDatabase object.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  I've read before that I should perform database operations in an AsyncTask, however I would prefer on getting the basics right before getting any deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize DatabaseImplementation and SQLiteDatabase inside onCreate method.

Comment: Oh great.  Thanks it worked.  One more question : where is the database saved once I run my application ?

Comment: There is a default path which you can access it directly with the db name through SQLiteOpenHelper, the full path will look like this: "data/data/com.example.testingdatabase/databases/youDbName"

Comment: What I meant is, should it be on the tablet or in my workspace?

Comment: It will be on the device, in that exactly path... on an emulator you can access it at "File Explorer" tab on Eclipse and even push it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pozzo Apps, you were very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseImplementation db ;

SQLiteDatabase dbWrite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     db  = new DatabaseImplementation(this);
     dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
     insertRecords();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize DatabaseImplementation and SQLiteDatabase in onCreate method.

like this :

```
DatabaseImplementation db ;
SQLiteDatabase dbWrite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     db  = new DatabaseImplementation(this);
     dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
     insertRecords();


}
```