# Finding database path is impossible

Tags: android

I am quite new to android development and right now I'm trying to create a database through a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.  I am positively sure that the data is being stored somewhere on my Nexus 7 (the device I'm using to test my applications), however I cannot find the path to the database.

I've looked around for other similar questions and all the answers point to finding the database at **data/data/com.example.projet_name/databases/database_name** but I do not have such a path on my device.

Any ideas on what the problem might be? Or perhaps there are other paths that I should look for?

Thanks for your time.

***EDITED :***

Please find my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676834/unable-to-instantiate-activity) from my previous post.

Now I am getting the following error when I run the application.  I hope it helps in some way.

```
07-17 08:28:20.130: E/libgps(486): LIBGPS: Cannot communicate (write) with a GPSD
07-17 08:28:20.130: E/libgps(486): IPC Communication Error, /tmp/11862727/customers/Asustek/Tabletandroid/../../../proprietary/deliverables/android/gps_interface/../gps_interface/gpsi_client/GpsiClient.cpp:1178 agps_ril_update_network_state
```

Comment: I edited the main post for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting the dbname as full path:

```
String DATABASE_NAME = "/data/data/"+packageName+"db.db";
```

or put your db in SD card:

```
String DATABASE_NAME= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+packageName+"db.db";
```

pass the dbPath in your code:

```
public DatabaseImplementation(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: Hi kevinhoo, I tried doing as you suggested and now I am getting the previous erro "Unfortunately, app_name has stopped. Maybe I am looking at the wrong folder? On my Nexus 7 I am entering ASTRO File Manager > sdcard > Android > data.  Is that where I should be looking for the database?

Comment: 1.which DATABSE_NAME did you use when you get the error? try replace "/data/data/" by context.getCacheDir()? 2.the sd card path in my galaxy is /storage/sdcard0/

Comment: I used both suggestions and both of them provided me with the same error. `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "testingdatabase/TestDatabase.db";` and  `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "/data/data/testingdatabase/TestDatabase.db";` With the `context.getCacheDir();` I haven't got any errors, however I still cannot find the database.  Funny enough I can't even find the package name at storage/sdcard/Android/data...

Comment: do you have /data/data/ dir in your device?

Comment: No, I do not. That is why I'm getting confused.

Comment: what do you use to check your files? in adb shell? or file explorer installed in your device?

Comment: I only have ASTRO File Manager on my device.  That is what I use to browse through the files.

Comment: can you find your platform-tools dir in your adb sdk dir. then run "adb.exe shell" to check it out your device?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to this.  Would you kindly explain how I can do that?

Comment: 1. find your adt install path, and find platform-tools folder, such as E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514\sdk\platform-tools 2.start cmd in your windows, goto the folder you found 3. run command "adb.exe shell"  you can check this article http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCommandLine/article.html

Comment: Sad so.. event if using a specific db path "context.getCacheDir()" to create a db? is it created successfully?

Comment: kevinhoo, thank you I figured it out.  Apparently the database is stored in some folder which is impossible for the user and developer to access.  I tried running a couple of statements and I confirm that the database has been stored.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get database which is stored in applicaiton package from device thn you will not get direct access from device /data/data/app packagename/databases/ ..you can access and modify using helperclass bt direct export nt poss AFAIK ... bt from emulator u cn gt

[image]

If you to export database from in sd card from application package

try this

```
private void copyFromDataPackgeToSdCard() throws IOException {
    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File appDataDir = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sdCard.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName()
                    + "//databases//"
                    + DatabaseImplementation.DATABASE_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = DatabaseImplementation.DATABASE_NAME;
            File currentDatabase = new File(appDataDir, currentDBPath);
            File backupDatabase = new File(sdCard, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDatabase.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDatabase)
                        .getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDatabase)
                        .getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("copyFromDataPackgeToSdCard", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not running the application on an emulator.  I'm running it on a real device.  From the file explorer, no other files / folders are stored under the data folder, nor under the sdcard folder.

Comment: AFAIK direct we cant access from file manager...you need to copy paste db.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by copy/paste database.