# Copy database to sdcard fails even though no error thrown

Tags: android, database, copy, sd-card

Here is my code:

```
try 
        {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String es= System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

            if (sd.canWrite()) 
            {                                   
                String currentDBPath = "/data/com.my.package/databases/my.db";
                String backupDBPath = "my_db_backup.db3";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(es, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }               
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("APP ERROR", "APP DB Backup", e);
        }
```

All executes successfully . The EXTERNAL_STORAGE path is : storage/emulated/legacy  . But when I use DDMS, the EXTERNAL_STORAGE path is there, but there  is no file present. I have an HTC One...

UPDATE: 11-01-2013
I tried all suggestions below,  no error is thrown though just like in my code, and leads me to believe that its MY phone thats just silently not allowing me to copy anything to my SD card. 
I have an HTC one...is there any setting or procedure I need to do with my phone prior to executing the "copy db to sd card" code?

Comment: have you given externa storege permision?

Comment: hi once check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693164/1140237

Comment: check this one also it may help u  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17922707/1140237

Comment: I have added external storage permission, sd.CanWrite() is false if permission is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this works like charm with me

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**NOTE :**

Just pass the name of database without specifying extension.

Like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                exportDatabse("my"); // Correct
                exportDatabse("my.db"); // Wrong
    }
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me. If I leave off the "db" extension,  sd.canWrite() is false.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one

```
void getDBBackUp(){
    File cacheDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"NewFolder");
    else
        cacheDir = getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String temp =""+c.get(Calendar.DATE) +"-"+ (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +"-"+ c.get(Calendar.YEAR) +"-"+ c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"-"+ c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +"-"+ c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    try {
       File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
       File dir = new File (sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/NewFolder");

       if (dir.canWrite()) {
           String currentDBPath = "//data//"+PACKAGE_NAME+"//databases//DatabaseName";
           String backupDBPath = "DB_"+temp;
           File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
           File backupDB = new File(dir, backupDBPath);

           AppLog.logString(TAG+"PACKAGE_NAME  : "+PACKAGE_NAME);
           AppLog.logString(TAG+"currentDBPath : "+currentDBPath);
           if (currentDB.exists()) {
               FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
               FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
               dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
               src.close();
               dst.close();
           }
           AppLog.logString(TAG+"backupDB : "+backupDB);
           ErrorDialog.dispDialog(LogInActivity.this, "Backup Store At: "+backupDB, "eLitePOS");
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: AppLog is nothing it's log.d and ErrorDialog is message dialog you can display toast also.. change database name also..

Comment: Thanks but does not work either. No error is thrown though just like in my code, and leads me to believe that its my phone thats just silently not allowing me to copy anything to my SD card. Arghhh....

Comment: @Mike it's your phone issue or anything other becuse this code work for me in many application and i had tested it on many device also

Comment: any idea what the issue could be on my phone?

Comment: which device you have? and try once to unplug cable i thing when sd card is in use with system it's can not write any thing so tyr it also

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check whether you have gave write permission for writing files to sdcard in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For reference check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Thanks